# Default symfony 2 htaccess redirect all requests without trailing slash to root page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

I have a problem with my symfony deployed to shared hosting

When I try to open page which not ended with slash I got redirected to home page for some reason

For example when I open this url http://example.com/current/web/about/test I redirected to http://example.com/current/web/

If I add slash to the end like http://example.com/current/web/about/test/ it works ok, but I want to use clean urls.

On my local machine this problem not reproduced

I have default .htaccess in web folder

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]


    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]


    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>       
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/        
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

route for url:

```
about:
    path: /about/{name}
    defaults: {_controller: TestWebAppBundle:About:index}
```

Comment: Is `/current/web/about/test/` a real directory?

Comment: no /current/web is real directory. request should be processed by app.php located here